# How to import octokit in browser

Tags: javascript, github, browser, github-api, octokit-js

tried to follow an [example from this](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents). To import octokit I first pasted the following lines into my html document as stated by adding the following lines:

```
<script type="module">
import { Octokit } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@octokit/core";
</script>
```

This just resulted in an `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Octokit is not defined`. Moving the line in script tags directly into the script.js file above the code just made one of the main functions appear as undefined (it handled a button click that authenticated a google account and then retrieved data from google sheets via the sheets API).

I then tried all this with new  html and js files, adding that code directly to the html had the same result but this time adding it to the start of the js file gives a `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module script.js:1`

Don't really know what to do from here so any help would be appreciated. [Did find this though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966543/how-to-use-request-js-by-octokit-on-browser) but it just says the issue is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to write your script logic in a separate `javascript` file, and then import that file in your `html` at the end of `body` element.

Here is an example of getting your repositories from GitHub:

`repos.js`

```
import { Octokit } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/octokit";
import { config } from "./config.js";

const GIT_KEY = config.API_KEY;

export const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: GIT_KEY,
});

const repo = await octokit.request(
  "GET /users/{username}/repos{?type,sort,direction,per_page,page}",
  {
    username: "your_username",
  }
);
console.log(repo);
```

`repos.html`:

```
<body>
  ...
  <script type="module" src="repos.js"></script>
</body>
```